# Adding a confirmation form before the add form of a content type

Tags: forms, plone, dexterity

One of our customers wants to add a terms of service page that has to be shown every time a user adds some specific content type, before the add form.

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: What do you mean by adding some specific content type? Like in file input?

Comment: for instance, when an user clicks on Add -> News Item she should be redirected to a terms of service page, then she will need to click on an Accept button and then she will see the normal Add form.

Comment: imho it would be easier to have a checkbox with a link to the terms of service page and the customers has to accept it.

Comment: Are you familiar with http://docs.zope.org/zope_secrets/hooks.html#traversal (zope.traversing.interfaces.IBeforeTraverseEvent) You could hook in based on what's currently in the request. Bu I'm not sure about redirecting in subscribers.

Comment: thanks, the checkbox sounds pretty interesting; I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a Dexterity content type, you can do this:

Create a custom form with your terms of service. In the form's button handler, redirect to the add form:

```
self.request.response.redirect(self.context.absolute_url() + '/++add++name.of.content.type')
```

Now in your type's factory info in portal_types, set the add_view_expr like this:

```
<property name="add_view_expr">string:${folder_url}/@@terms-of-service</property>
```

so it goes to the custom TOS form when you click the type in the factory menu, instead of directly to the add form.

(Note: a downside of this approach is that if the user enters the URL of the add form directly, they can bypass the TOS form.)

Comment: I ended up by using your solution because it was in fact a Dexterity-based content type and the downside was not a problem in our case.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution could be to use a cookie/session_data_manager/token/you-name-it that on the custom AddForm for that content type checks if exists.

If it doesn't redirect to that Terms of Service form that redirects back to the Addform where, now it will accept to proceed becuase the cookie/session_data_manager/token/you-name-it will be there.

Answer (score 1):

An idea: when you are adding new content types (AT based content types, this will not work for Dexterity ones) you are calling

```
http://something/createObject?type_name=Document
```

You can transform the `createObject` script into an view that display you disclaimer form, with validation on submit.

When user accept the disclaimer you will redirect the use to something like

```
http://plone4.gest.unipd.it:8080/gest/it/realCreateObject?type_name=Document
```

where `realCreateObject` is a copy/paste of the original Plone `createObject` script.

However: the suggestion of Mathias above is really good: just add a fake checkbox field with a validation.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment of the question. I would advise adding a checkbox to the content.

For AT content you can add a BooleanField

```python
...

atapi.BooleanField(
    name='acceptConditions',
    schemata='default',
    required=False,
    default=False,
    validators=('acceptConditions', ),
    widget=atapi.BooleanWidget(
        label=_(u'label_accept_conditions', default='Conditions'),
        description=_(
            u'help_accept_conditions',
            default='Please accept the <a target="_blank" '
                    'href="./conditions_view">'
                    'conditions<a/>.')
    ),
)
...
```

With a condition on the widget (In this case a browser view, which checks if the boolean field should be visible or not).

```python
YourSchema['acceptConditions'].widget.setCondition(
    'python: here.restrictedTraverse("@@show_condition_field").show()')
```

Comment: I agree with you, this was probably the easier one, but the customer use case was a little bit different and that's why I ended up with David's solution.